# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_theme()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress, I am trying to install a new plugin by uploading it to theme via my FTP program. when I do that and when I try to activate that theme in the wordpress i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_theme()

I have seen few fixes such as rename it inside the theme folder among some other fixes none of them really help me, what can I do to get this problem fixed?
I am using WordPress 3.2.1.

Comment: Update WordPress version to latest.

Comment: @Milap when I do that I get unexpected error during API request!!

Comment: WordPress always recommend to update version whenever available, if you are facing trouble with that, first solve that, above issue will be solved automatically.

Comment: @Milap well the hing is that I tried to solve that, I couldnt find a fix i google it it was a bout the timeout problem which didnt help in my case. SO I am not sure what is the cause of that, i got that error while trying to install new plugin, then I did it manually thorugh FTP program. now when I wnt to install new theme i see this error. I am not sure how to fi xnay of them since none of the fixes I found really helped me!

Comment: If you get multiple issues and not able to solve it alone, i prefer to hire WP expert.

Comment: @Milap I am at learning process and Im trying to elarn it so I know what is wrong. but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue if you haven't updated the root `wp-settings.php` file. Try grabbing another download, deleting `wp-settings.php` in root and just uploading this file.